# can't get delete function to work properly AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, class, flash

I have a Volcano class. It's purpose is to randomly spray lavaMass. 
In the main class I have made it so that when my character hits the lava, everything is removed, and the deleteLava() function is called.

My problem is that with the deleteLava() function, my Volcano class stops making lava after a few 'deaths'.

Now i gets a little complicated to explain.
I found out that inside the deleteLava() function I should also remove the lavaMass from the array, for it to keep making lava no matter how many 'deaths'.
I used 'lavaSpray.shift();', and tried 'splice'.. 
And this worked! Except that it doesn't delete all the lavaMass, so everytime the character dies a few of the lavaMass objects keeps hanging around in the level, not moving. So after many 'deaths' there is a lot of lavaMass objects just standing still, not moving and not being deleted.

Here's the volcano class:

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Volcano extends MovieClip {

    var lavaSpray:Array = [];
    var lavaNum:Number;
    var world:World;

    public function LavaThing() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, makeLava)
    }

    public function deleteLava()
    {
        this.parent.removeChild(this)
        for (var m = 0; m < lavaSpray.length; m++) {
        if (lavaSpray[m].parent) { 
        lavaSpray[m].parent.removeChild(lavaSpray[m]); 
            }
        }
    }

    function makeLava (e:Event)
    {
        lavaNum = Math.random()*70
        if (lavaSpray.length<20)
            {
            if (lavaNum > 68.15)
                {
                    var lavaMass = new LavaMass();
                    lavaSpray.push(lavaMass);
                    addChild(lavaMass);
                    lavaMass.scaleY = 0.5;
                    lavaMass.scaleX = 0.5;
                    lavaMass.x += 90;
                    lavaMass.y += Math.random()*30
                    lavaMass.y -= Math.random()*30
                }
            }

        for each (lavaMass in lavaSpray)
            {
                lavaMass.x += 4;
                if (lavaMass.parent &&  lavaMass.x > 800)
            {
            lavaMass.parent.removeChild(lavaMass);
            lavaSpray.shift();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I hope someone knows what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance.

I put up a video with my problem: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYxYHB7rcgY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You shouldn't ever use parent in your code - good oop rule.  Removing parent from your code will force you to delete stuff properly.  You shouldn't try to delete an instance from within the instance.  Just put everything in a container class and have the container control creation and deletion.  The parent clip holds the volcano and the lava that comes out of the volcano.

Comment: @moot Thanks, I will look up container class!

Comment: Container class isn't special, just a class you make to hold the volcano, lava, and whatever else.  Put all clips in holder clips for many reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issues is:

you don't remove the `ENTER_FRAME` Event Listener when you delete the lava.

removing the child doesn't mean you deleted it's listener.
so you may remove all the lava , but still the `ENTER_FRAME` creates more !
you have to remove it your self.

so you have to add

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, makeLava)
```

as the first line at your function `deleteLava()`

....
or you may add

```
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemoved)
```

and create `onRemoved(e:Event){}` function
then inside this function remove any listener you Added , including the `ENTER_FRAME` & the `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`

---

try to read more about these subjects

Game Loop
entity system framework 
Pool Object pattern

I may but links , but I prefer you Google them , and read from different resources - whatever the language they are explained with -

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't remove the eventlistener, since I need remove the volcanos when the character dies, and then add it again when the player decides to try the level again. And then when it's added again it has no eventlistener.

Comment: I put up a video to show the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYxYHB7rcgY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I assume you initialize Class `Volcano` once , then use `addChild()` to add it , and `removeChild()` to remove it but you never use use `volcano = new Volcano()` again , Right ?

in this case , all you have to do is to remove the `ENTER_FRAME` event from the constructor and add another listener :
`addEventListener(Event.Add_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);`

then create function `onAddedToStage(e:Event)` and add the `ENTER_FRAME` inside it .

now your volcano know when it is added to the stage again , and start listening

Comment: but again you need to change the **game loop** model you are doing now and use the **update** pattern or the **Entity System**

Answer (score 0):

just for clarrifying your question.. You added the lavamass inside the volacano class? and you need to remove lavamass or volcano ? Dp you get any error during compilation? Also i encountered some thing like this when developing a shooting game, the removed bullets shows up after removing the bullerts. What i did was , i just added the bullets into a empty movieclip and removed the entire clip.

Comment: In my game I have a lot of levels. In my main class I have an array with 5 volcanos in it, so I can add the volcanos where I want them, which is different for each level. Every time the character dies everything is deleted, and then i have a 'retry button' which adds everything again in the start position. I need to be able to remove every lava object inside the volcano class, but I can't null the volcano itself because I need it again.

Comment: And when i try to delete the volcano it either stops spraying lava after some 'retrys' or if I try to delete all the lava, from the array inside the volcano class, with lavaSpray.shift(); some few of the lava object doesn't get deleted and sticks around forever, which of course is piling up, but then it keeps spraying lava. My problem is deleting the lava objects properly from the array inside the volcano class.

Comment: Here's a video I captured to show my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYxYHB7rcgY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I think you really need to remove the enteframe listener when deleting the object. and also you need removeChild(lavaMass) only this. Don't need to refer the parent. As mentioned by moot , it's a bad idea . And also you need to remove from Array then you need remove from the displayobject. Apart from this teh code sems good.